# Join Two tables and get the output data in same columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables A and B,
Table A have 3 cols and table B have 2 cols.

Table A data:

| name | id | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 1 | ab |
| xyz2 | 2 | ab1 |
| xyz3 | 3 | ab2 |

Table B data:

| name | id |
| --- | --- |
| xyz3 | 3 |
| abc2 | 4 |

Output I want:

| name | id | city | match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 1 | ab | no |
| xyz2 | 2 | ab1 | no |
| xyz3 | 3 | ab2 | yes |
| abc2 | 4 | NULL | no |

I have tried this but it is giving op in different column:

```
select *
from TableA a
full outer join TableB b
on a.id= b.id
```

Output I'm getting

| name | id | city | name | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 1 | ab | null | null |
| xyz2 | 2 | ab1 | null | null |
| xyz3 | 3 | ab2 | xyz3 | 3 |
| Null | null | null | abc2 | 4 |

Output I want:

| name | id | city | match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 1 | ab | no |
| xyz2 | 2 | ab1 | no |
| xyz3 | 3 | ab2 | yes |
| abc2 | 4 | NULL | no |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is all I think you need to do - union the two tables and then aggregate, counting rows to identify matches with duplicates from both tables:

```
with c as (
    select name, id, city
    from a union all
    select name, id, null
    from b
)
select name, id, Max(city) City,
  case when Count(*)> 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end Match
from c
group by name, id;
```

See [demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RVdUUABC)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UNION` between `TableA` and `TableB`, a `CASE` statement to check if an `id` in `TableA` is also in`TableB` (for your `match` column), and a `NOT EXISTS` subquery to `TableA` in `TableB`'s `WHERE` clause to only return rows that exist in `TableB`.

```
SELECT *, 
  CASE WHEN id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM TableB) THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS match
FROM TableA a
   UNION
SELECT *, NULL AS city, 'no' AS match
FROM TableB b 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableA a2 WHERE a2.id = b.id)
ORDER BY id ASC
```

**Result:**

```
| name | id | city | match  |
|------|----|------|--------|
| xyz  | 1  | ab   | no     |
| xyz2 | 2  | ab1  | no     |
| xyz3 | 3  | ab2  | yes    |
| abc2 | 4  | null | no     |
```

**Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/5acuoo7z).**

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
select a.name, a.id, a.city, 
  case when b.id is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end as [Match]
from tableA a
  left join tableB b  on b.name = a.name and b.id = a. id
union 
select b.name, b.id, a.city,
  case when a.id is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end as [Match]
from tableB b left join tableA a on b.name = a.name and b.id = a. id) tmp
  order by id  ;
```

Here is [DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/bCXcnRJC)